# Need to prevent a dropdown list being added over and over

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps code with PHP MySql, and as per the code from their developers site I've got the map working. However, as part of their code they add a  menu (which contains all of the returned options) under the map. The problem is that when i carry out another search I get another  added rather than the one that is already there being updated with the new information. I think that the problem is something to dow with the locationSelect object, I would appreciate some help with it:

```
  //Variables that we need later
var map;
var markers = [];
var infoWindow;
var locationSelect;
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40,-100);
var addmap = ('<div id="map" style="visibility:visible;"></div>');
var addLocationSelect = '</br><div id="locationSelectDiv"><select id="locationSelect"></select></div>';
var subject_text = "";
var subject_id = "";

 function load(myLatlng) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  }); 
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
  locationSelect.onchange = function() {
    var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (markerNum != "none"){
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    }
  };
}

function searchLocations() {
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
    var subject_text =  $('#search_subject>option:selected').text();
    var subject_id =  $('#search_subject>option:selected').val();
    console.log(address);
    console.log(subject_text);
    console.log(subject_id);

 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      $('#container').replaceWith(addmap);

       $("#map").slideDown("4000", function(){    
                    $('#map').after(addLocationSelect);
                           load();
      searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);

     });
            } else {
     alert(address + ' not found');
   }
 });
}

function clearLocations() {
     infoWindow.close();
     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       markers[i].setMap(null);
     }
     markers.length = 0;
 locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = "none";
     option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
     locationSelect.appendChild(option);

   }

function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations();
     var searchUrl = 'findlocations.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=20';
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
         createOption(name, distance, i); 
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
      locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }
function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
  var html = "<h3>" + name + "</h3><p>The biography will go here</p>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}

function createOption(name, distance, num) {
   var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = num;
  option.innerHTML = name + " is " + distance.toFixed(1) + "miles away";
  locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`createOption()` does exactly as it says it creates a new option. If you want to add the results of a new search (including markers) you will need to add these to the existing locations.

***pseudo code* NOT tested**

GLOBAL `var flag = 0;\\Set to 0 for 1st Search`

IN `searchLocationsNear()` add following

```
searchLocationsNear(center) {
    if(flag ==0){//1st Search
        clearLocations();
    }else{//Sugsequent Searches
        flag =1;
    }
```

Comment: Dear Dave - That's great but and now the new search results are added into the list, but I wanted to make it so that the previous search results are removed and replaced with the new search results (rather than simple add it into the list) - is that possible

Comment: also this will still add another dropdown list which I dont want - I'd like to keep the same dropdown box but change the content in it to reflect the new search results

Comment: @Mobaz I have run your origonal code(adding the functions missing) with my own database. When you enter a new search the origonal dropdown list is cleared and the new results added as designed.see my [**demo**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php). What exactly do you want to do different from this?

Comment: strange - when I run it i'm getting multiple dropdowns added, but managed to get it fixed (added an answer) note the     $('#container').replaceWith(addmap); has moved to the top of the function and that seems to sort the problem - thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the locationSelect select dropdown is added every time searchLocations function returns. I just moved it to the top of the function and it's added fresh every time the submit button is entered, which will only provide a single dropdown with the results for the map.

```
function searchLocations() {
    $('#container').replaceWith(addmap);
    var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
    alert(address);
    var subject_text =  $('#search_subject>option:selected').text();
    var subject_id =  $('#search_subject>option:selected').val();
    console.log(address);
    console.log(subject_text);
    console.log(subject_id);
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       $("#map").slideDown("4000", function(){                            
                           load();
      searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);

     });
            } else {
     alert(address + ' not found');
   }
 });
```

}